# Can I call a recursive function in assembly without using jal?

Tags: assembly, mips

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yblTE.png)

I am making a function so search for a number in an array. My teacher said that I MUST use the jal command, but I don't see why using it and I manage to get it done without it. Why should I use the jal command?

Comment: Because without `jal`, its not recursive.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please no [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Thanks!

Comment: Also, please tag assembly questions with the relevant CPU architecture.  I guess this is MIPS?

Answer (score 1):

There's no requirement to use `jal` to call functions.  Recursion is simply one function calling itself — and there's no requirement to use `jal` in function calling.

That being said, the easiest way to make a function call is to use `jal`, because it does several things for you:

1. assign to the `$ra` register the location to return to in the caller, aka the return address (sometimes called linkage).
2. transfer control of the CPU from the caller to the callee, by changing the PC to the callee's start address.

These two operations are required for function calling.  (Further, parameter passing and return value passing are also generally needed.)  However, the code sequence you use to accomplish the two above operations does not have to include `jal` — just that `jal` is pretty convenient for doing them.

There are a number of alternatives:

1. convert from recursive to iterative algorithm, then no calling is needed.
2. use indirect function call instruction `jalr`
3. load the return address into the `$ra` register and `j` jump to the callee

---

However, the code you're showing doesn't accomplish the above.  Let's note that a function should be callable from multiple callers.  Thus, some function, `f`, should be callable from `main` or from `g` or from `h`.  The return address — hidden from the programmer in C and other languages, but visible in assembly as `$ra` — is a parameter that tells `f` who to return to.  It is dynamically computed so that `f` can be called from `main`, `g`, and `h` all in the same run of the same program (or called from two or more different places in the code of `main`, for example).

In the case of recursion, we would have `f` being called from at least one caller like `main`, but also being called from itself, making at least 2 distinct callers.  The `$ra` parameter informs `f` who & where to go back when its done.